# I have to click a button twice in order for the desired effect to happen - useState not updating properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Works.tsx

const buttonChoices and const works were not posted as I was trying to keep the post short, however they do exist.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import { BsChevronUp } from 'react-icons/bs'
import TopButton from './TopButton/TopButton'

const Works = () => {

const [Buttons, setButtons] = useState(false)

    const [everythingButton, setEverythingButton] = useState(false)

    const [catagories, setCatagories] =  useState<string[]>([])

    const intersection = works.filter(work => catagories.includes(work.type));

    useEffect(() => {
        const newArray = catagories

        setCatagories(newArray)

    }, [catagories])

    return (
        <div className='works-container'>

            <div className='works-top-container'> Our Work </div>

            <div className='works-top-buttons-container'>
                {
                
                Buttons ? 
                (
                    <div className='everything-buttons-full'>
                        <div>Show Me : </div>
                           {
                             buttonChoices.map((button, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <TopButton
                                    key={idx}
                                    isHighLighted = { catagories.includes(button.type) }
                                    catagories={catagories}
                                    setCatagories={setCatagories}
                                    buttonName={button.type}
                                />
                            )
                        })}
                        <div
                            style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                            onClick={() => setButtons(false)}>
                            <BsChevronUp size={18} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className='everything-buttons'>
                        <div> Work With Us </div>
                        <div className='show-me'>
                            {' '}Show Me :{' '}
                            <div
                                className='everything-choice'
                                onClick={() => setButtons(true)}>
                                {
                                    "Everything"
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>




            <div className='our-works-container'>
                    {
                        catagories.includes('Everything') ?

                        works.map( (item, idx) => {

                            return (
                                <img key={idx} style={{ height:"100px", width:"100px"}} src={item.image} />
                            )
            
                        })


                        : 

                        intersection.map( (item, idx) => {

                            return (
                                <img key={idx} style={{ height:"100px", width:"100px"}} src={item.image} />
                            )
            
                        })
                    }
            </div>



        </div>
    )
}

export default Works
```

TopButton.tsx

```
import React, { SetStateAction, useEffect } from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import { useState } from 'react'


interface ITopButtonProps {
    buttonName: string
    setCatagories : React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>
    catagories: string[]
    isHighLighted: boolean
}

const TopButton = (props :ITopButtonProps) => {



    const { buttonName, setCatagories, isHighLighted, catagories } = props

    
    const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false)


    const handleClick = (catagoryType: string) => {

    if (buttonClicked) {

           setCatagories([...catagories.filter(catagory => catagory !== catagoryType)] )

    } else {

          if (catagoryType != 'Everything') {

            setCatagories([...catagories.filter(catagory => catagory != 'Everything'), catagoryType]) 

          } 
          
          else if(catagoryType === 'Everything') {

            setCatagories([catagoryType]) 

          }

    }

    setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked)
}



  return (
    <div onClick={() => handleClick(buttonName) } 
    className={  isHighLighted ? 'buttons-clicked'  :  'buttons' }>{buttonName}</div>
  )
}

export default TopButton
```

I know that you can pass down a setter function to a child that then updates the useState of the parent. However it seems that for some reason I need to the  component twice or three times in order for the state to properly update.

Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong and what the proper ways of passing setter functions down to child components to avoid this issue?

I have tried using a useEffect inside of Works.tsx and setting the dependency to "catagories" so catagories is up to date everything it changes.

Comment: Try changing the `onClick` handler in the `TopButton` div to be `() => setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked)`. Then change `handleClick` in `TopButton` to be a `useEffect`, with `[buttonClicked]` as the dependency array.